# Can you still use the least significant difference test even if the F test is not significant?

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

Can you still used the least significant difference test even if the F test is not significant?

Comment: An F-test of what?  If an ANOVA, how many levels, variables, interactions etc?  If it's just two levels they don't report anything different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.  If you want to graph your data and use LSDs to indicate that things were not significant in the tests, and also demonstrate the range of values you could have found significant for a particular comparison then go right ahead.

If you want to go on a fishing expedition within your data then be advised your chances of finding making a Type I error will be substantially greater than alpha.

Comment: John its for multiple linear regression (levels of categorical variable). Im supposed to get a significant F (but I am not). Maybe because the reference group is wrong?

Comment: @Tom It is Q&A not a forum, so please use comments for comments. Moreover I see you lost your account -- I have fixed that, but please register here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login .

Comment: Add more to your question, edit it until it better reflects your problem, what you've tried, and things like your guess about the reference group.